# Distinguish between img & svg when passed down as a prop in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

Assume I have a component `<MyComponent /> that takes in prop called`src`the`src`prop can take in`svg`as well as a`img`

```
 <MyComponent src={someSvgComponent} />
```

Or

```
 <MyComponent src={someImgComponent} />
```

How do I check if the passed prop in `src` is an image or an svg? An image can be of type jpeg|jpg|png|gif

Now the `src` prop can either pass the file or the path of the file.

Comment: by file you mean base 64 encoded svg/img data ?

Comment: Yes by file I mean that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution imo is to add a second `srcType` prop to `MyComponent` that will tell it what type of image is being passed as a prop. That's assuming that you know what image is being passed in beforehand.

```
<MyComponent src={someSvgComponent} srcType="svg" />

<MyComponent src={someImgComponent} srcType="img" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Since both file src and the base 64 encoded string contains the format you can just check the following within MyComponent or else as if you know image type before hand pass it as prop to your MyComponent.

If your base 64 string is like following str.includes directly works else you guess mime type from base64 data (**data:image/type;base64,** which won't contain this part).

```
'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAA...5CYII='
'data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyBoZWlnaHQ9IjUxMn..'
```

Else

```
function guessImageMime(data){
  if(data.charAt(0)=='P'){
    return "svg";
  } else if(data.charAt(0)=='/'){
    return "jpeg";
  } else if(data.charAt(0)=='R'){
    return "gif";
  } else if(data.charAt(0)=='i'){
    return "png";
  }
}

if(this.props.src.includes('svg') || guessImageMime(this.props.src) === 'svg') {
    //it is svg
} else {
    //it is image in other format
}
```

Comment: `can either pass the file or the path of the file.` Meaning it will not always be a string filename with an extension. It also needs to support a base64 string.

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda edited the answer see if it is more meaningful now.